# Cannot send excel file to server, asp.net doesn't see any files.IFormFile is null in API

Tags: angularjs

on client-side:
Uploading excel file.
`<div>
    <form>
        <div>
            <label for="myFileField">Select a file: </label>
            <input type="file" demo-file-model="myFile" class="form-control" id="myFileField" />
        </div>
        <button ng-click="uploadFile()" class="btn btn-primary">Upload File</button>
    </form>
</div>`

angular controller:

```
 $scope.uploadFile = function () {
        var file = $scope.myFile;

        Service.fileUploadAll(file,
            function (response) {
    });


fileUploadAll(file) {
        var fileFormData = new FormData();
        fileFormData.append('file', file);
        return this.promiser.post('/api/fileUpload', fileFormData);
```

}

```
[HttpPost("fileUpload")]

    public IActionResult fileUploadAll(IFormFile file)
    {
```

// Do some 
        }

I'm working on Asp.NET Core .
Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need add header and set content type here like this :

```
fileUploadAll(file) {
        var fileFormData = new FormData();
        fileFormData.append('file', file);
        return this.promiser.post('/api/fileUpload', fileFormData, {transformRequest: angular.identity, headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}});
```

Let me know please.

Comment: what change i need to do in api side and bcoz it gives supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.

Comment: Are you getting file at server side?

Comment: after adding that header and set content type.. it gives error ... Error is:

Comment: supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target

Comment: You haven't specified ng-model variable in :  <input type="file" demo-file-model="myFile" class="form-control" id="myFileField" />